# How to create a duplicate map object i java?

Tags: java

I have a tree map object tm2 of type `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>>`. I want to make a copy (duplicate) out of it.  I tried cloning  :   `TreeMap tm = (TreeMap) tm2.clone()` but did not help. Please suggest me how to get a copy entirely( so that copied Object does not refere to the original objects member)

Comment: What needs to be cloned, and why? Just the map? Or the map and its lists. Or the map, its lists, and every SomeObject instance inside the lists? If you need more than the map, you'll need to do that explicitely (using loops). You should really explain what you want to achieve at a higher level, because cloning is probably not the best solution.

Comment: @JBNizet - I think we will need to do a deep-copy otherwise the references will be same in both the maps... right?

Comment: @TheLostMind: yes, but that could be expected, or that could be a problem. We can't know.

Comment: "so that copied Object does not refer to the original objects member" - as @JBNizet suggested, you will need to copy field by field (deep copy)..

Comment: @JBNizet both the Map and the list. The list is in the value field of the TreeMap. Actually I have been trying to implement an Retrieval System. I have used the TreeMap as my InvertedIndex dataStructure

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in "layers". First, create a `copySomeObject` method that takes a `SomeObject` instance and returns a copy of it. Since you haven't given any information about that class, I can't show you quite what it would look like, but — something like this:

```
private SomeObject copySomeObject(final SomeObject someObject) {
    final SomeObject ret = new SomeObject();
    ret.setFoo(someObject.foo());
    ret.setBar(someObject.bar());
    return ret;
}
```

You can then use the above `copySomeObject` method to create a `copyList` method that takes an `ArrayList<SomeObject>` instance and returns a copy of it:

```
private ArrayList<SomeObject> copyList(final ArrayList<SomeObject> list) {
    final ArrayList<SomeObject> ret = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
    for (final SomeObject someObject : list) {
        ret.add(copySomeObject(someObject));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Lastly, you can use the above `copyList` method to create a `copyMap` method that takes a `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>>` instance and returns a copy of it:

```
private TreeMap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>> copyMap
        (final TreeMap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>> map) {
    final TreeList<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>> ret =
        new TreeList<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>>();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        ret.put(entry.getKey(), copyList(entry.getValue());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

That's the method you actually want to call elsewhere in your program.

(Note that splitting this up into three methods is not technically necessary — each method is called in one place, so you could write the whole thing as a big nested loop — but it helps greatly with readability and maintainability.)